# ios-deploy installation failed

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, xcode, cordova

So I am trying to install ios-deploy with npm and I'm having this error:

```
sudo npm install -g ios-deploy
npm WARN lifecycle ios-deploy@1.9.0~preinstall: cannot run in wd %s %s (wd=%s) ios-deploy@1.9.0 ./src/scripts/check_reqs.js && xcodebuild /usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/ios-deploy-298c9491
npm ERR! Darwin 16.0.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "ios-deploy"
npm ERR! node v6.7.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.3
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ios-deploy/build/Release/ios-deploy
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall chmod

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ios-deploy/build/Release/ios-deploy'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ios-deploy/build/Release/ios-deploy'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
sudo npm install -g ios-deploy --unsafe-perm=true
```