# Cannot install ios-deploy with npm

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm following the instructions at https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup?guide=native for ios.

I got react installed fine but when it comes time to try to fire up the app in the simulator with `npx react-native run-ios` I get an error:

`error Failed to install the app on the device because we couldn't execute the "ios-deploy" command. Please install it by running "npm install -g ios-deploy" and try again.`

When I try that, however, I get a wall of errors:

```
> $ npm install -g --verbose ios-deploy
npm verb cli /usr/local/Cellar/node/20.0.0/bin/node /usr/local/bin/npm
npm info using npm@9.6.4
npm info using node@v20.0.0
npm verb title npm install ios-deploy
npm verb argv "install" "--global" "--loglevel" "verbose" "ios-deploy"
npm verb logfile logs-max:10 dir:/Users/steve/.npm/_logs/2023-04-19T13_54_42_397Z-
npm verb logfile /Users/steve/.npm/_logs/2023-04-19T13_54_42_397Z-debug-0.log
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/ios-deploy 13ms (cache hit)
npm info run ios-deploy@1.12.1 preinstall node_modules/ios-deploy ./src/scripts/check_reqs.js && xcodebuild
npm info run ios-deploy@1.12.1 preinstall { code: 65, signal: null }
npm verb stack Error: command failed
npm verb stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/promise-spawn/lib/index.js:53:27)
npm verb stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:511:28)
npm verb stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1098:16)
npm verb stack     at Socket.<anonymous> (node:internal/child_process:456:11)
npm verb stack     at Socket.emit (node:events:511:28)
npm verb stack     at Pipe.<anonymous> (node:net:334:12)
npm verb pkgid ios-deploy@1.12.1
npm verb cwd /Users/steve/workshop/AwesomeProject
npm verb Darwin 22.4.0
npm verb node v20.0.0
npm verb npm  v9.6.4
npm ERR! code 65
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ios-deploy
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c ./src/scripts/check_reqs.js && xcodebuild
npm ERR! Command line invocation:
npm ERR!     /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild
npm ERR!
npm ERR! User defaults from command line:
npm ERR!     IDEPackageSupportUseBuiltinSCM = YES
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Computing target dependency graph and provisioning inputs
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Create build description
npm ERR! Build description signature: 7704f57eed1e3af474161959e18555e2
npm ERR! Build description path: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ios-deploy/build/XCBuildData/7704f57eed1e3af474161959e18555e2.xcbuilddata
npm ERR!
npm ERR! warning: Building targets in manual order is deprecated - check "Parallelize build for command-line builds" in the project editor, or set DISABLE_MANUAL_TARGET_ORDER_BUILD_WARNING in any of the ta
rgets in the current build to suppress this warning
npm ERR! CreateBuildDirectory /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ios-deploy/build
npm ERR!     cd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ios-deploy/ios-deploy.xcodeproj
npm ERR!     builtin-create-build-directory /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ios-deploy/build

<snip>

npm ERR! ** BUILD FAILED **
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The following build commands failed:
npm ERR!        Ld /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ios-deploy/build/ios-deploy.build/Release/ios-deploy.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Binary/ios-deploy normal x86_64 (in target 'ios-deploy' from project 'ios-deploy')
npm ERR! (1 failure)
npm verb exit 65
```

I looked at the troubleshooting guide at https://reactnative.dev/docs/troubleshooting but didn't find any reference to this problem.

I tried the soludtion at https://stackoverflow.com/a/40422440/1641112 but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Per the recommendation when submitting an issue at https://github.com/ios-control/ios-deploy, I looked at the readme file at https://github.com/ios-control/ios-deploy/blob/master/README.md

It says to install it with brew:

`brew install ios-deploy`

I did so and it appears to work now (though with some build failure errors for the app itself). However, it's odd the official documentation is wrong and I'd like to know why following it did not work.